# How to create obb file for android expansion

Tags: android

I tried creating OBB file for Android expansion using Jobb tool. But it is not getting created. I have tried with jobb and jobb.bat also but same result I am getting. To define the problem cleary, I have attached the image of my CMD console as below:

[image]

I have read the http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html and I have googled but I could not find the solution of the problem. If Jobb does not work is any other way to create the OBB file. Please help me. Thank in advance.